# DB2 Decimal type not formatted correctly in C# DataSet

Tags: c#, db2, odbc, decimal, dataadapter

Due to reasons, we're having to transform our code to get DB2 data through an Odbc connection instead of OleDb. But we're having some difficulties with `DECIMAL` types.

We're calling a stored procedure on DB2 and filling the data in a `DataSet` using an `OdbcDataAdapter`. The procedure in the DB2 database returns a `DECIMAL(5,2)` with the value `100.00` but in the `DataSet` the value is `10000` (the point seperator is gone).

This was not an issue when we were using the OleDb driver, but we have to use Odbc now. We're using the IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER which is installed with the full IBM DB2 client (11.5.7.0).

I've read that using `OdbcDataReader.GetDouble()` would fix this, but it would be a lot of work to transform all our code to use DataReaders instead of DataAdapters. The SP also returns multiple result sets, so the DataSet is easier to use.

Here's a summized form of our code:

```
// ...
using (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection db2Conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connStringDB2))
{
    OdbcCommand cmdDB2 = new OdbcCommand();
    cmdDB2.CommandText = "call SP()";
    cmdDB2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdDB2.Connection = db2Conn;
    cmdDB2.CommandTimeout = 1800;

    dsDB2 = new DataSet();
    OdbcDataAdapter daDB2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmdDB2);
    daDB2.Fill(dsDB2);
    db2Conn.Close();
}
// ...
// We're opening a connection to our SQL Server database to push the data of the DB2 procedure to
// All the result sets are visited as shown below
// ...
foreach (DataRow dr in dsDB2.Tables[8].Rows)
{
    cmdSql.Parameters["@Name"].Value = dr["name"];
    cmdSql.Parameters["@Value"].Value = dr["value"];
    cmdSql.Parameters["@Percentage"].Value = dr["percentage"];  // here there's a mismatch with the DECIMAL(5,2) value 100.00, which is given as 10000
    cmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
// ...
```

Comment: @mao I've edited the post. We're using the IBM DB2 ODBC Driver installed with the full client 11.5.7.0.

Comment: on the  (Microsoft Windows) hostname where c# is running, what are the regional-settings, specifically for decimal separator? And in your connection string (or db2cli.ini, or db2dsdriver.cfg) are you setting any attributes that influence presentation of decmals?

Comment: @mao The db2cli.ini and db2dsdriver.cfg have no locale/culture settings and we're only referencing the DSN (and credentials) in our connection string. The regional settings are indeed local ones that use a comma and not a point. Is there a way to still make it work without changing the regional settings? Policy doesn't allow us to change it.

Comment: I would analyze a cli trace to check how the stored-procedure result-set(s) column(s) are described at cli level (specifically the decimal(x,y) column(s)), and whether the cli returns a correct decimal value for those column(s) to its caller, or not. It's essential to know which component is removing the separator, to know what to adjust. It may be possible to adjust the culture for the da.